# Converting list to map have improper output

Tags: apex, visualforce, integration, salesforce-id, collection

**Tring to convert** `List <MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c>` to `Map<String,MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c>`

These are the fields in Object :- MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c

```
Select  ID,MBT_SFFB__Facebook_ID__c,MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_ID__c,MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_Name__c,MBT_SFFB__Facebook_User_Relates_To_Page__c,MBT_SFFB__Image__c from MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c
```

Map Manipulation

```
map<String,MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c> objmapfacebookallpages = new map<String,MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c>();
list<MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c> objlstalldbMBT_SFFB_Facebook_Page =new list<MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c>([Select  ID,MBT_SFFB__Facebook_ID__c,MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_ID__c,MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_Name__c,MBT_SFFB__Facebook_User_Relates_To_Page__c,MBT_SFFB__Image__c from MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c]);
       if(objlstalldbMBT_SFFB_Facebook_Page.size()>0)
       {
            for(MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c objfbpguser : objlstalldbMBT_SFFB_Facebook_Page)         
            {
                objmapfacebookallpages.put(objfbpguser.MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_ID__c,objfbpguser);                    
            }

        }
System.Debug(objmapfacebookallpages);
```

**Output:-** `{11470233432895363662=MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c:{MBT_SFFB__Facebook_ID__c=11470233432895363662, MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_ID__c=16162323367178658991, MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_Name__c=Busyday, MBT_SFFB__Facebook_User_Relates_To_Page__c=a0H2800000B6nR0EAJ, MBT_SFFB__Image__c=https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c15.0.50.50/p50x50/399548_10149999285987789_1102888142_n.png?oh=82d551fbd5c70ae9e2ad123aaebbc331&oe=58E6646A, Id=a0I2800000EhUi2EAF}}`

**The only last Record i found.**

I want all records.

Comment: There are few things you can check on. First check the size of your list `objlstalldbMBT_SFFB_Facebook_Page`. Then check whether `MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_ID__c` field value is unique over all the records

Comment: What's the use of creating a List and then converting it to Map? You can directly have a for loop iteration on  MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c and create a Map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the below optimized code. Please run the soql in the developer console/workbench to find how many records are there in `MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c` object.

```
Map<String, MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c> objmapfacebookallpages = new Map<String, MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c>();

for(MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c obj : [Select  ID, MBT_SFFB__Facebook_ID__c, MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_ID__c, MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_Name__c, MBT_SFFB__Facebook_User_Relates_To_Page__c, MBT_SFFB__Image__c from MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c]) {
    objmapfacebookallpages.put(obj.MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_ID__c,obj);
}

system.debug(objmapfacebookallpages);
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner

```
Map<Id, MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c> objmapfacebookallpages = new Map<Id, MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c>([Select  ID, MBT_SFFB__Facebook_ID__c, MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_ID__c, MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_Name__c, MBT_SFFB__Facebook_User_Relates_To_Page__c, MBT_SFFB__Image__c from MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c]);
system.debug(objmapfacebookallpages);
```